# "command not found" errors when executing TCL script in OSX

Tags: macos, tcl

I'm trying to execute [this TCL script](http://wiki.tcl.tk/41305), which should batch normalise a folder of mp3's.  I'm on OSX Yosemite (ffmpeg fully installed).  The line is:

```
./normalise.tcl mp3folder
```

which (inc. sudo) returns:

```
./normalise.tcl: line 37: proc: command not found
./normalise.tcl: line 38: global: command not found
./normalise.tcl: line 40: switch: command not found
./normalise.tcl: line 42: puts: command not found
./normalise.tcl: line 43: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
./normalise.tcl: line 43: `        }'
```

.. and then directs shell to the inbuilt help documentation.  I have no experience of this language so am reading up, but haven't come across anything so far to explain it.  Very grateful for an idea what's going wrong.

---

Edit

The `-d` option suggested in script comments seems to have no effect.

The full script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#\
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

# Copyright 2015 Tholis Biroi (tholis DOT biroi AT yahoo DOT it)
#
# This file is part of 'normalize.tcl'.
# 'normalize.tcl' is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify 
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or 
# (at your option) any later version.
# 'normalize.tcl' is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but 
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. 
#
# See the GNU General Public License for more details.
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License 
# along with 'normalize.tcl'. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
#
#
#
# 'normalize.tcl' is a simple TCL script that drives 'ffmpeg' to normalise
# audio levels for a group of mp3 files.
# For each mp3 file found into a directory, it reads the mean volume level, 
# calculates the average level among various files and adjusts the volume
# level of each of them.
#

# Global debugging variable
# To override this option set '-d' on the command line
set debugOn false

# log --
#
# puts "" wrapper 
#
proc log {label args} {
    global debugOn

    switch $label {
        "info" {
            puts {*}$args
        }
        "error" {
            puts "error: [join {*}$args]" 
        }
        "warning" {
            puts "warning: [join {*}$args]" 
        }
        "debug" {
            if {$debugOn == "true"} {
                puts "debug: [join {*}$args]" 
            }
        }
        default {
            # do nothing in any case
        }
    }
}


# get_volumes --
#
# Exec 'ffmpeg' in order to get the volume mean level
#
#
proc get_volume {mp3} {
    if {$mp3 == {}} {
        log error "Empty file name."
        return {}
    }

    # Set volume variable
    set volume {}

    # Set 'ffmpeg' command
    set cmd "ffmpeg  -i \"$mp3\" -af \"volumedetect\" -f null /dev/null"    
    log debug "'ffmpeg' cmd= $cmd"

    # Exec 'ffmpeg'
    if {[catch {eval exec -ignorestderr $cmd 2>@1} out]} {
        log error "'ffmpeg' execution command failed."
        log debug "reason= $out"
        return {}
    }

    # In order to avoid 'case sensitive' parsing, the output of the 
    # command is converted to uppercase
    set Out [string toupper $out]    
    log debug "'ffmpeg' out= $Out"

    # Now scan the out a line at time searching for 'MEAN_VOLUME:' 
    # output string label
    set lines [split $Out "\n"]

    foreach line $lines {
        log debug "$line"
        # first of all search for 'VOLUMEDETECT' string and if foud
        # search for 'MEAN_VOLUME:' string.
        if {[string first VOLUMEDETECT $line] == -1} {
            # Not found, skip line parsing 
            continue
        }

        # 'VOLUMEDETECT' string found, search for 'MEAN_VOLUME' string
        set pos [string first MEAN_VOLUME $line]
        if { $pos != -1} {
            set start [expr {$pos + 11}]
            set volStr [string range $line $start end]
            log debug "volStr= $volStr"

            # Extract and trim the first word as volume
            set words [split $volStr]
            log debug "words= $words"
            set volume [string trim [lindex $words 1]]
            log debug "volume= $volume"
        }
    }

    return $volume
} ;# end get_volume


# set_volume --
#
# Exec 'ffmpeg' to re-encode the mp3
#
proc set_volume {mp3 actualVol targetVol} {
    if {($mp3 == {}) || ($actualVol == {}) || ($actualVol == {})} {
        log error "One or more parameter are empty"
        return {}
    }

    # Create filename output
    set mp3Root [file rootname $mp3]
    set mp3OutFile "${mp3Root}.norm.mp3"

    # If normalized file already exists, will be deleted
    if {[file exists $mp3OutFile]} {
        catch {file delete -force -- $mp3OutFile}
    }

    # calculate the delta volume
    set deltaVol [expr {$targetVol - $actualVol}]

    # Set 'ffmpeg' command
    set cmd "ffmpeg -y -i \"$mp3\"  -af \"volume=${deltaVol}dB\" \"$mp3OutFile\""

    # Exec 'ffmpeg'
    if {[catch {eval exec -ignorestderr $cmd 2>@1} out]} {
        log error "'ffmpeg' execution command failed."
        log debug "reason= $out"
        return {}
    }   

    # For debug purposes
    set Out [string toupper $out]    
    log debug "'ffmpeg' out= $Out"

    return $deltaVol
} ;# end set_volume


# byebye --
#
proc byebye {} {
    log info ""
    log info "Bye!"
    log info ""
} ;# end byebye


# print_help --
# 
# Prints a little help
#
proc print_help {} {
    global argv0

    log info ""
    log info "Usage: $argv0 \[-h|--help\]|<mp3 dir>"
    log info ""
    log info "-h|--help  Print thi help"
    log info "<mp3 dir>  Directory path containing mp3 to normalize"
    log info ""

    byebye
    return
} ;# end print_help

# Main -----------------------------------------------------------------
log info ""
log info "MP3 normalizer v0.9 21 mar 2015"
log info ""
log info ""

# Save current dir
set currDir [pwd]
log debug "Working dir= $currDir"

# Control input parameters to setup working dir 
# If no parameter is passed a little help is printed on screen
if {$argc == 0} {
    print_help
    exit 0
}

# If more than one parameter is passed
if {$argc != 1} {
    log error "Wrong number of arguments."
    log error "Use '-h' or '--help' option to print usage info."

    byebye
    exit 1
}

# If only one paramter is passed, it could be the help option or the
# desired working path
if {([lindex $argv 0] == "-h") || ([lindex $argv 0] == "--help")} {
    print_help
    exit 0
}

# Save the passed workDir in order to make some controls
set workDir [lindex $argv 0]

# The path passed must be a directory path
if { ![file isdirectory $workDir] } {
    log error "The argument passed is not a valid directory path"

    byebye
    exit 1
}

# The argument passed must be an existing directory
if { ![file exists $workDir] } {
    log error "Directory '$workDir' does not exists"

    byebye
    exit 1
}

# Move on working dir
cd $workDir

# Get the list of files in the current directory
set mp3Files [glob -nocomplain *.mp3]

if {$mp3Files == {}} {
    log info "No .mp3 files found on working dir: '$workDir'"

    byebye
    exit 1
}

# Exclude from this list files with exetension *.norm.mp3"
set mp3FileList {}
foreach mp3 $mp3Files {
    set rootFname [file rootname $mp3]
    set ext [file extension $rootFname]

    if {$ext == ".norm"} {
        # Skip already normalized files from mp3 list
        continue
    }

    lappend mp3FileList $mp3
}


# Init the mp3 array
#set mp3Ar {}

log info "List of file mp3 to be normalized:"

# Foreach *.mp3 file 
foreach mp3 $mp3FileList {
    log info "   '$mp3'"

    # Extract volumes
    set vol [get_volume $mp3]
    if {$vol == {}} {
        log warning "No volume information found for file: $mp3"
    } else {
        # Fill the array of volumes
        set mp3Ar($mp3) $vol
    }
}

log info ""

# parray only for debugging
#parray mp3Ar

# Calculating the average volume
set avgVol 0
set mp3List  [array names mp3Ar]
set numFiles [llength $mp3List]

foreach mp3 $mp3List {
    set avgVol [expr {$mp3Ar($mp3) + $avgVol}]
}
set avgVolume [expr {$avgVol/double($numFiles)}]
set avgVol [format "%0.1f" $avgVolume]

log info "Avg Volume= $avgVol"
log info ""

# Now foreach file calculate delta volume to normalize it
log info "File normalization at $avgVol dB"
foreach mp3 $mp3List {
    log info "    '$mp3' from $mp3Ar($mp3) to $avgVol"
    if {[set_volume $mp3 $mp3Ar($mp3) $avgVol] == {}} {
        log info "warning: Set volume failed for file '$mp3'"
    }
}
log info ""
log info "Done."

# Before exit return to run dir
cd $currDir

byebye

exit 0
```

Comment: I am not familiar with TCL either, however what's happening is `/bin/sh` is executing those TCL instructions, and it doesn't understand it.  I think you could change the hash-bang line to `#! /usr/bin/env tcl` and comment-out that `tclsh` line.

Comment: Do you have any spaces after the slash on the 2nd line?

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the new hash-bang without success, as well as commenting out 'tclsh' line.  Then reverted to original code and inexplicably this time it works!  Maybe some syntactic subtleties I need to learn..

I'll delete this question shortly..

Comment: Have you tried this: `tclsh ./normalise.tcl mp3folder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, that script is being actually executed by the bourne shell (`/bin/sh`) in its entirety, and not Tcl. Since the two languages have fairly different syntaxes, that gets you those error messages.

But why would this be happening?

Well, the key lines are these:

```
#!/bin/sh
#\
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}
```

That's supposed to run the script initially with the bourne shell, and then transfer execution to Tcl (since standard shell `exec` *replaces* the current process executable). It's based on the fact that the shell doesn't think a backslash at the end of a line in a comment is special, and yet Tcl treats that as meaning that the following line is also part of the comment. Different rules.

Yet that's failing. I'm guessing that the problem is that `tclsh` isn't on your path (Really? It's a standard part of my OSX system.) and that so the `exec` is failing and the remainder of the script is therefore being interpreted. Which is more than a bit strange. You say you're going via `sudo` so that might be a problem, but there really ought to be a `tclsh` in one of the directories that `sudo` puts on the `PATH` by default (`/usr/bin`), so that might not be what's going on.

The recommended approach at this point is to change those three lines of the script to use a more modern idiom that's a single line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh
```

You can use the fully-specified name for `tclsh` in there as well. Or you can try launching the code with:

```
tclsh ./normalise.tcl mp3folder
```

That last step is also a good way to detect if there are other problems; it overrides the lookup of the script interpreter and lets you focus on what happens after that.

Comment: Thanks - useful description of the problem. The original script did (somewhat inexplicably) work in the end, so something must've changed.